# Does order matter in REST api express, ie. get -> post -> put -> delete?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Does it matter if you implement the get method before another method such as post for example implement app.post() before app.get()? I am not sure why there would be significance in changing the order, but in the express app that I built if I implemented post before get, my data would buffer and then be posted every other call, the posting was inconsistent. When I switched the order the issue was fixed.

This is the code for the requests

```
const xhrPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
const xhrGet = new XMLHttpRequest();
//sends data to DB
xhrPost.open("POST", '/endgame', true);
xhrPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhrPost.send(JSON.stringify({
  playerScore: score
}));
//when data is done being posted, get list of scores from db
xhrPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    xhrGet.open("GET", '/endgame', true);
    xhrGet.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhrGet.send();
  }
}
//when scores retrieved display results on console
xhrGet.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.table(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    var data = (JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    ctx.fillText(data[0].playerScore, 50, 150);
  }
};
```

and this is the server side code

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, (error, database) => {
    if (error) return process.exit(1)
    const db = database.db('js-snake-scores')
    app.post('/endgame', (req, res) => {
        let score = req.body
        db.collection('scores')
            .insert(score, (error, results) => {
                if (error) return
                res.send(results)
            })
    })
    app.get('/endgame', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('scores')
            .find({}, {
                playerScore: 1
            }).toArray((err, data) => {
                if (err) return next(err)
                res.send(data)
            })
    })

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
})
```

Comment: I think order don't matter as long as you call the right method. Order only matter when you have router with same method and nearly same router name such as `app.get('/image/:id')` and `app.get('image/test')` If you put router `:id` before `test`, `:id` always will run first. It's better if you post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it matter if you implement the get method before another method such as post for example implement app.post() before app.get()?

No.  Order matters only when two routes would handle both the same path and the same method.  So, since `app.post()` and `app.get()` each only intercept different methods, they don't compete in any way and thus their relative ordering to each other does not matter.  Only one will ever trigger on a GET and only the other one will ever trigger on a POST regardless of their order of definition.

If you saw a difference in behavior due to the order, then it must have been due to some other effect besides just an `app.get()` and an `app.post()` with the same path because those two are not ever activated on the same request.  If we could see the two implementations of code where you say order mattered when you switched them, then we could likely offer you a better idea of why you saw a difference in behavior.   `app.post()` and `app.get()` ordering by themselves would not cause what you described.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code, the behaviour I am observing is that in some cases only on the next get request will the data posted be returned in the get, whereas in other cases the data posted appears in the same get request.

Comment: @rsingh - So, this question is about server code, but you just added your client code?;  Not sure what to do with that.  The issue would be in your server code.

Comment: I have added the server side code as well and I just noticed something the Get request is being called before the Post not sure why, thanks again for all the assistance

Comment: @rsingh - I think you probably have some sort of race condition or timing issue with your database where the result of the `.insert()` isn't immediately available.  I don't know that DB well enough to know more about that.